# Create haskel socket client

Tags: sockets, haskell, networking, connection

I try to connect to created socket by haskell:

```
-- Logger
  putStrLn "Create socket"
  sock_logger <- socket AF_INET Stream 0     
  putStrLn "Bind socket"           
  connect sock_logger (SockAddrInet 5000 0)    
  putStrLn "Listen socket"  
  listen sock_logger 2                                  
  putStrLn "Logger listening on port 5000..."
  (conn_logger, _) <- accept sock_logger                       
  putStrLn "Logger connection accepted"
```

Scocket already created by other application. But after `connect sock_logger (SockAddrInet 5000 0)` i get

```
helloworld-exe.EXE: Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 440>: failed (Cannot assign requested address (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL))
```

How can i connect to socket as client (without creation new socket)
All sockets i create with SockAddrInet 5000 0. Can it depends on addlress (maybe need 127.0.0.1 instead localhost?)

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is listening on that port?

Comment: Hm, I'm not a socket expert, but isn't `listen` usually done after a `bind`, not a `connect`? i.e. the pattern for servers is `bind`, `listen`, `accept`*, then you can send and receive on the result, while for clients it is `connect`, then you can send and receive on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [`tupleToHostAddress`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.2.7/docs/Network-Socket.html#v:tupleToHostAddress), as in

```
connect sock_logger (SockAddrInet 5000 (tupleToHostAddress (127, 0, 0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Daniel Wagner, it's  really need to use `tupleToHostAddress (127, 0, 0, 1)` and `listen ...` is wrong. Right version:

```
  putStrLn "Create socket"
  sock_logger <- socket AF_INET Stream 0     
  putStrLn "Bind socket"           
  connect sock_logger (SockAddrInet 5000 (tupleToHostAddress (127, 0, 0, 1)))                      
  putStrLn "Connected to logger on port 5000..."
```